# Oracle SQL - Keep null value if it's the only one, else avoid null value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table :

```
Table1
-----------------
ID         VAL       
-----------------
1          A
1          B
1          null
2          null
3          B
3          null
4          B
4          C
5          null
```

I want to get this result :

If the only value is null then return null, else return non null
   values

```
Table1
-----------------
ID         VAL       
-----------------
1          A
1          B
2          null
3          B
4          B
4          C  
5          null
```

I tried using Over Partition By with a Case but my statement became too complicated with several subqueries, if think there should be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COUNT( value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id )` analytic function will count the rows where `value` is not-`NULL` for each `id`. You can use it to filter the rows like this:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS num_values
  FROM   yourtable t
)
WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
OR     num_values = 0;
```

> If the only value is null then return null, else return non null values

If you want to ensure that `NULL` is only returned if there is exactly one row for the `id` then:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( * ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS num_rows
  FROM   yourtable t
)
WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
OR     num_rows = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE val IS NOT NULL OR
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'VALUED'
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
    AND t2.val IS NOT NULL)
```